# divide by zero exception handling in Linux

Tags: exception, linux-kernel, signals

I am curious to understand the divide by zero exception handling in linux. When divide by zero operation is performed, a trap is generated i.e. `INT0` is sent to the processor and ultimately `SIGFPE` signal is sent to the process that performed the operation.

As I see, the divide by zero exception is registered in `trap_init()` function as

```
set_trap_gate(0, &divide_error);
```

I want to know in detail, what all happens in between the `INT0` being generated and before the `SIGFPE` being sent to the process?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why linux kernel use trap gate to handle divide\_error exception?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8530794/why-linux-kernel-use-trap-gate-to-handle-divide-error-exception) Check out this **[answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15501983/319204)**.

Answer (score 11):

Trap handler is registered in the `trap_init` function from [arch/x86/kernel/traps.c](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/x86/kernel/traps.c?v=3.12#L728)

```
void __init trap_init(void)
..
    set_intr_gate(X86_TRAP_DE, &divide_error);
```

`set_intr_gate` writes the address of the handler function into `idt_table` [x86/include/asm/desc.h](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/x86/include/asm/desc.h?v=3.12#L336).

How is the divide_error function defined? As a [macro in `traps.c`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/x86/kernel/traps.c?v=3.12#L214)

```
DO_ERROR_INFO(X86_TRAP_DE, SIGFPE, "divide error", divide_error, FPE_INTDIV,
         regs->ip)
```

And the macro `DO_ERROR_INFO` is defined [a bit above in the same traps.c](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/x86/kernel/traps.c?v=3.12#L193):

```
193 #define DO_ERROR_INFO(trapnr, signr, str, name, sicode, siaddr)         \
194 dotraplinkage void do_##name(struct pt_regs *regs, long error_code)     \
195 {                                                                       \
196         siginfo_t info;                                                 \
197         enum ctx_state prev_state;                                      \
198                                                                         \
199         info.si_signo = signr;                                          \
200         info.si_errno = 0;                                              \
201         info.si_code = sicode;                                          \
202         info.si_addr = (void __user *)siaddr;                           \
203         prev_state = exception_enter();                                 \
204         if (notify_die(DIE_TRAP, str, regs, error_code,                 \
205                         trapnr, signr) == NOTIFY_STOP) {                \
206                 exception_exit(prev_state);                             \
207                 return;                                                 \
208         }                                                               \
209         conditional_sti(regs);                                          \
210         do_trap(trapnr, signr, str, regs, error_code, &info);           \
211         exception_exit(prev_state);                                     \
212 }
```

(Actually it defines the `do_divide_error` function which is called by the small asm-coded stub "entry point" with prepared arguments. The macro is defined in `entry_32.S` as [`ENTRY(divide_error)`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/x86/kernel/entry_32.S?v=3.12#L939) and `entry_64.S` as [macro `zeroentry`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/x86/kernel/entry_64.S?v=3.12#L1205): [`1303 zeroentry divide_error do_divide_error`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/x86/kernel/entry_64.S?v=3.12#L1303))

So, when a user divides by zero (and this operation reaches the retirement buffer in OoO), hardware generates a trap, sets %eip to `divide_error` stub, it sets up the frame and calls the C function `do_divide_error`. The function `do_divide_error` will create the `siginfo_t` struct describing the error (signo=`SIGFPE`, addr= address of failed instruction,etc), then it will try to inform all notifiers, registered with [`register_die_notifier`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/notifier.c#L528) (actually it is a hook, sometimes used by [the in-kernel debugger "kgdb"](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/x86/kernel/kgdb.c#L607); kprobe's [kprobe_exceptions_notify](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/x86/kernel/kprobes/core.c#L959) - only for int3 or gpf; uprobe's [`arch_uprobe_exception_notify`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/x86/kernel/uprobes.c#L625) - again only int3, etc).

Because DIE_TRAP is usually not blocked by the notifier, the [`do_trap` function](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/x86/kernel/traps.c?v=3.12#L139) will be called. It has a short code of `do_trap`:

```
139 static void __kprobes
140 do_trap(int trapnr, int signr, char *str, struct pt_regs *regs,
141         long error_code, siginfo_t *info)
142 {
143         struct task_struct *tsk = current;
...
157         tsk->thread.error_code = error_code;
158         tsk->thread.trap_nr = trapnr;
170 
171         if (info)
172                 force_sig_info(signr, info, tsk);
   ...
175 }
```

`do_trap` will send a signal to the `current` process with [`force_sig_info`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/signal.c?v=3.12#L1222), which will "Force a signal that the process can't ignore".. If there is an active debugger for the process (our current process is `ptrace`-ed by gdb or strace), then `send_signal` will translate the signal SIGFPE to the current process from `do_trap` into SIGTRAP to debugger. If no debugger - the signal SIGFPE should kill our process while saving the core file, because that is the default action for SIGFPE (check [man 7 signal](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) in the section "Standard signals", search for SIGFPE in the table).

The process can't set SIGFPE to ignore it (I'm not sure here: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419527/can-i-ignore-a-sigfpe-resulting-from-division-by-zero)), but it can define its own signal handler to handle the signal ([example of handing SIGFPE](http://technopark02.blogspot.ru/2005/10/handling-sigfpe.html) [another](http://man7.org/tlpi/code/online/dist/signals/demo_SIGFPE.c.html)). This handler may just print %eip from siginfo, run `backtrace()` and die; or it even may try to recover the situation and return to the failed instruction. This may be useful for example in some JITs like `qemu`, `java`, or `valgrind`; or in high-level languages like `java` or `ghc`, which can turn SIGFPE into a language exception and programs in these languages can handle the exception (for example, spaghetti from [openjdk is in `hotspot/src/os/linux/vm/os_linux.cpp`](http://code.metager.de/source/xref/openjdk/jdk8/hotspot/src/os/linux/vm/os_linux.cpp)).

There is a list of SIGFPE handlers in debian via codesearch for [siagaction SIGFPE](http://codesearch.debian.net/search?q=sigaction.*SIGFPE) or for [signal SIGFPE](http://codesearch.debian.net/search?q=signal.*%5C%28.*SIGFPE)