# Catching / disabling SIGFPE exceptions from assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-64, integer-division

I get a SIGFPE exception when dividing by 0 in x86 assembly using `idiv`. How would I disable it from assembly? Do I need a syscall or can it be done directly in x86?

Reproduction:

test.asm

```
default rel
global WinMain

section .data 

section .text
WinMain:
    mov rcx, 0
    mov rdx, 0
    idiv rcx
```

Commands:

> nasm -f win64 test.asm
> gcc test.obj
> gdb a
> run

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TL:DR: you can't make the hardware not fault with a `#DE` exception, and it's non-trivial to resume execution after skipping the faulting instruction in a signal handler to "repair" the situation. (You'd also want to set RDX and RAX to some special values like `-1`, `0`, or a noticeable value like `0xcccccccccccccccc`.  Or depending on what might make the rest of your program silently do something useful(?) instead of crash again a different way, perhaps `+1`.)

For actual floating-point exceptions, the x87 FPU and SSE (via MXCSR) default to having exceptions masks, so you get NaN in the destination on invalid ops like division by zero, no hardware exception.  POSIX requires that if there's a fault for any arithmetic operation and the OS delivers a signal about it, that signal must be SIGFPE.

---

The best you could do is catch SIGFPE with a signal handler ([`sigaction(2)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigaction.2.html#NOTES) on POSIX OSes like Linux).  Strange that you're talking about SIGFPE for a program with a `WinMain` entry point, unless perhaps Windows SEH (structured exception handling) also uses the same SIGFPE name?

Ignoring it with SIG_IGN is undefined according to POSIX, and in practice would result in an infinite loop if you ignore the signal or have a signal-handler return without doing anything.  The hardware `#DE` fault has a return address pointing at the faulting instruction (same as for page faults), both so the handler can see which instruction it is, and so repairing the situation somehow (like a #PF handler normally does) will re-run the instruction to hopefully not fault on the next try.

So your handler should check if `si_code == FPE_INTDIV`.  If so, it could try to advance the program counter to past the end of the faulting instruction, to run as if it hadn't executed at all, leaving FLAGS and RDX:RAX unmodified.  (Or your signal handler could set them to some consistent values.)

A thread's registers are accessible and modifyable by a Linux signal handler that runs in it.  *[Getting fault address that generated a UNIX signal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5119288/getting-fault-address-that-generated-a-unix-signal)* covers the `ucontext_t` stuff as well, containing GPRs including RAX and RDX but also RIP, the program counter.

x86-64 instructions are variable length.  You'll have to decode machine code from the address in RIP, skipping prefixes, looking for an opcode byte that's an opcode for `idiv` or `div`.  If so, advance RIP to after that instruction to skip it.  Instruction-length decoding is non-trivial since memory source operands with variable-length addressing modes are possible: you'll have to decode ModRM and the optional SIB enough to figure out the total instruction length.  (x86-64 is designed to make this not too painful so hardware can do it efficiently: you don't need to remember the bits from the REX prefix if any while doing instruction-length decoding for the part after the prefixes: *[rbp not allowed as SIB base?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52522544/rbp-not-allowed-as-sib-base*.))

---

There's no FLAGS / control register / other hardware setting that will make `div` and `idiv` not raise `#DE` divide exception on divisor = 0 or on the quotient not fitting into the operand-size.  e.g. into RAX for 64-bit `idiv rcx`, like for `INT64_MIN / -1` which also faults on x86-64.

Or for `(unsigned long)-1 / 1` with signed division like you're doing by zero-extending into RDX:RAX before signed `idiv`.  Normally use `cqo` / `idiv` to sign-extend RAX into RDX:RAX before signed division, or `xor edx,edx` / `div` to zero-extend into RDX before unsigned division.
(*[When and why do we sign extend and use cdq with mul/div?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36464879/when-and-why-do-we-sign-extend-and-use-cdq-with-mul-div)*)

You can mask FP exception, and the default x87 and SSE (MXCSR) state is for FP exceptions to be masked, so normally the only thing that can raise SIGFPE on an x86-64 system is integer division.  (Or perhaps an `into` instruction, trap if the OF flag is set.)

---

Related:

- [Can I ignore a SIGFPE resulting from division by zero?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419527/can-i-ignore-a-sigfpe-resulting-from-division-by-zero) (An X-Y problem so the answers don't actually address how to do that.)
- [Why does integer division by -1 (negative one) result in FPE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46378104/why-does-integer-division-by-1-negative-one-result-in-fpe) - fun fact: `INT_MIN / x` where `x=-1` doesn't fault on ARM, neither does division by 0.  See that for more background on what POSIX requires about signals in this case.
- [Getting fault address that generated a UNIX signal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5119288/getting-fault-address-that-generated-a-unix-signal)

Comment: I think you could technically disable interrupts to avoid the #DE, but that's not something a user process can do.

Comment: "Strange that you're talking about SIGFPE for a program with a WinMain entry point, unless perhaps Windows SEH (structured exception handling) also uses the same SIGFPE name?". 
Maybe gdb is showing me SIGFPE on windows even though it is called something else? I have no idea otherwise.

Comment: Maybe one way if "fixing" the situation is to overwrite rdx and the operand with 1 and 1, before returning to the address of the idiv instruction (granted that the handler shares the same register state, i don't even know if that is the case?)

Comment: @fuz Disabling interrupts (clearing `EFLAGS.IF`) only masks (maskable) hardware interrupts, not exceptions.

Comment: @BasicBlock: Decoding enough to figure out the register or memory location of the source operand is even harder than decoding enough to find the instruction length.  If you're going to modify registers, I think RDX=RAX=something is the only sane way, also setting RIP=end of idiv (so it *doesn't* re-run on return from the signal or SEH handler).  The code is expecting RDX:RAX to be written, and expecting the source operand to stay the same.  The source operand could even be memory in a read-only page, like `idiv dword [divisor_table + rcx*4]`.  And decoding the full addressing mode is harder.

Comment: Typo? "You'd also want to set RDX and RAX to some special values like `-1`, `-0`, ... ". How would you set `-0` ?

Comment: BTW in an SEH handler on Windows you would get exception code 0xC0000094 aka EXCEPTION_INT_DIVIDE_BY_ZERO, but leave it to a unix-land tool like gdb to pretend that the whole universe is unix...

Comment: @SepRoland: Yes, typo.  I was probably thinking 0 or +1